# Upper and Lower Games in Zero-Sum Games

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, differential-games

I am working on some theory related to controls in the context of stochastic games, and I am a bit confused on some terminologies for zero-sum games.

Suppose we have a zero-sum game with two players.
Let the first players' inputs be $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, whose goal is to *minimize* the payoff function $J(U,V)$.
Let the second players' inputs be $V \in \mathbb{R}^{\ell}$, whose goal is to *maximize* the payoff function $J(U,V)$.
In my context, the first player is called the "controller" and the second player is called the "stopper".

I am currently reading a paper that states the following:

*The upper game is a scheme in which the stopper chooses $V$ based on the information it has on the control $U$, and the upper value is defined as*

$$
\mathcal{V}^+ = \inf_{U\in\mathbb{R}^{m}}\sup_{V\in\mathbb{R}^{\ell}} J(U,V).
$$

*Similarly, the lower game is a scheme in which the controller chooses $U$ based on the information it has on the control $V$, and the lower value is defined by*

$$
\mathcal{V}^{-} = \sup_{V\in\mathbb{R}^{\ell}}\inf_{U\in\mathbb{R}^{m}} J(U,V).
$$

Now I know from the minimax theorem that $\mathcal{V}^{-} \leq \mathcal{V}^{+}$ and they are only equal to each other at a saddle point (equilibrium).

My question is regarding the *definitions* of the upper and lower games.
Looking at the equation for the upper value, how does it make sense that the upper game is a game in which the *stopper* plays based on the information it has on the controller if the first optimization is over $V$ and the second optimization is over $U$.
The way I'm interpreting the upper value is that the stopper optimizes the cost, and then *based on the optimal stopper input*, the controller then optimizes the resulting payoff, so the stopper acts first, and the controller best follows after.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the order of the player's choices the wrong way round. In the upper game, the stopper is allowed to  make his or her choice of $\ V\ $ depend on the controller's choice of $\ U\ $. In practice, he or she would only be able to do this if the controller had already chosen $\ U\ $.  That is, it is the *controller*, not the stopper, who makes the first choice.

If the controller chooses $\ U\ $, then the stopper should choose $\ V^*(U)\ $ to make the payoff $\ J\big(U,V^*(U)\big)\ $ as close as possible to $\ 
\sup_\limits{V\in\mathbb{R}^\ell}J(U,V)\ $. When the controller chooses $\ U\ $, however, he or she can reasonably suppose that the the stopper, knowing the value of $\ U\ $, will choose $\ V^*(U)\ $, so the best value for him or her to choose would be one which makes $\ 
\sup_\limits{V\in\mathbb{R}^\ell}J(U,V)\ $ as close as possible to $\ \inf_\limits{U\in\mathbb{R}^m}\sup_\limits{V\in\mathbb{R}^\ell}J(U,V)\ $.

Comment: Ok I think I get it. Let me summarize here so you validate my reasoning: In the upper game, assume some $U$, then stopper chooses $V$ to maximize payoff, then given $V^*(U)$ choose $U^*(V^*)$ to minimize payoff. For the lower game, assume some $V$, then controller chooses $U$ to minimize payoff, then given $U^*(V)$ choose $V^*(U^*)$ to maximize payoff. Correct? And in equilibrium these two should equal!

Comment: Yes, you've got it.  But in general, when each player has to make his or her choice  without knowing that made by the other,  a saddle point ("equilibrium") in pure strategies (i.e elements of $\ U\ $ and $\ V\ $) will not usually exist. In these circumstances the inequality $\ \cal{V}^-\le \cal{V}^+\ $ will usually (but not always) be *strict*. This can sometimes be remedied by allowing the players to choose their strategies randomly in secret ("mixed strategies") and replacing the payoff function by its expected value.